# image is blinking using the method drawInRect what am i doing wrong

Tags: iphone

My code is here.

```
-(void)displayPacketData:(NSData*)decompressedData:(CEZCmdZLIBCompress*)data
{
        Byte* d=[decompressedData bytes];
    int width=data->iWidth;
    int height=data->iHeight;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerPixel    = 4;
    size_t bytesPerRow      = (width * bitsPerComponent * bytesPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    size_t dataSize         = bytesPerRow * height;
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate([decompressedData bytes], width, height, 
                                    bitsPerComponent, 
                                    bytesPerRow, colorSpace, 
                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst  | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
    layer1 = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context,(struct CGSize){ width, height }, NULL);

    if( layer1 == NULL )
    {
        NSLog(@"Layer could not be created");
    }
    layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer1);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height);

    //CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *result = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef] retain];
    m_image=result;
    x = data->iX;
    y = data->iY;
    h = height;
    w = width;
    //CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    //CGContextRelease(context);
    //free(data);    
    //[result drawInRect:CGRectMake(10.0, 30.0, x, y)];
    //CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context,CGPointZero,layer1);
    //CGContextDrawImage(layerContext, CGRectMake(10.0+x, 30.0+y, w, h), result.CGImage);
    //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
  [m_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(10.0+x, 30.0+y, w, h)];
}
```

Comment: If you expect people to put some effort into answering your question, you might put some effort into constructing your question. What are you seeing? What do you expect to see? How are the two methods you posted being called?

Comment: With a bit more info you will probably get a great answer, but we really need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my piece of advice: use UIImageView instead. You shouldn't draw image every time `drawRect:` occurs. Image loading and drawing is controlled by system pretty good, so all you need is to set UIImage object to UIImageView image property. If you check documentation of UIImageView you'll see that it doesn't call drawRect: method at all.

Comment: Thanx for your advise but i need to use the drawRect: method.